# I am trying to automate an install with Active Directory to a server core box?

Tags: scripting, active-directory, windows

I am trying to automate an install with Active Directory to a server core box?

I assume I need to set up a script.  Any ideas on how to go about this.

Comment: Are you referring to installing the Active Directory role?  Do you need it installed at OS install-time or are you just asking how to do it from the console?

Answer (score 0):

If this is Windows Server 2012, you can [do it all in PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574166.aspx):

```
PS:\> Import-Module ServerManager
PS:\> Add-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-Services
PS:\> Install-ADForest -DomainName corp.contoso.com
```

If your in Windows Server 2008 R2, then you can install the role as in the above, but then you'll script dcpromo for an unattended install:

```
[DCInstall]
 InstallDNS=Yes
 ConfirmGC=Yes
 NewDomain=forest
 NewDomainDNSName=corp.contoso.com
 DomainNetBiosName=CORP
 ReplicaOrNewDomain=domain
 ForestLevel=4
 DomainLevel=4
 DatabasePath="%systemroot%\\ntds"
 LogPath="%systemroot%\\ntds"
 SYSVOLPath="%systemroot%\\SYSVOL"
 SafeModeAdminPassword=C0mpl3xP@ssw0rd!
 RebootOnCompletion=Yes
```